# FindControl returns null in OnRowCommand Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with few controls in it and I'm trying to get these controls in OnRowCommand event by using the FindControl method, but it always returns null.

This is the gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service Type">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Fund_Service_Type") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlServiceType" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Method">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Fund_Method") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFundMethod" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Source">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Fund_Source") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFundSource" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Fund_Amount") %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fund_Amount")%>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText="" ShowHeader="false">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRedirect" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ID") %>' CommandName="CompleteTransaction" Text="Complete Transaction"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And here is the row command event

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName.Equals("CompleteTransaction"))
        {                
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); // Get the current row
            DropDownList ddlServiceType = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("ddlServiceType");//retuns null

            GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
            DropDownList name = (DropDownList)gvr.Cells[0].FindControl("ddlServiceType"); //also returns null
            Server.Transfer("~/Transaction.aspx");
        }
    }
```

what I'm trying to do is get the selected row so and values from its controls, so that I can use them in Transaction page.

**Edit:** The FindControl method is working fine in RowUpdating and RowDataBound events

Comment: have you tried : `gvr.FindControl("ddlServiceType")` ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I just did, it also returns null.

Comment: try this : `GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);` and  then: `gvr.FindControl("ddlServiceType");`

Comment: Maybe it should be `Cells[1]` since ddlServiceType is in the second column.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad nope, still returning null

Comment: Did you try selectedRow.FindControl("ddlServiceType") ???

Comment: try this in your code it will Work `(Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblstatus")`

Comment: @JohnWu Tried using different indexes for cells too, still can't find the control.

Comment: @adityashrivastava thanks using labels worked for me. But my code is something like this

Comment: @adityashrivastava  
Label name1 = (Label)selectedRow.FindControl("lblServiceType");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your DropDownLists is in the `EditItemTemplate`, you need to use the `EditIndex` to get the correct row.

```
DropDownList ddlServiceType = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("ddlServiceType");
ddlServiceType.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Comment: Although I got it to work with labels, but I'll still mark your answer as accepted, since it was what I was initially looking for. Thanks for your help though :)

Answer (score 2):

this may help you out

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName.Equals("CompleteTransaction"))
        {                
           int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); // Get the current row 

            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
            Label lblName = (Label)row.FindControl("lblName")
            DropDownList drpList= (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddlServiceType");
            lblName.Text = drpList.SelectedValue;             
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I already got it to work with labels since I only needed the text for selected item.